# vim cant map <C-Tab> to :tabnext

Tags: vim, configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, configuration-files

I have the following mappings in my .vimrc:

```
map <C-S-Tab> :tabprevious<CR>
nmap <C-S-Tab> :tabprevious<CR>
imap <C-S-Tab> <Esc>:tabprevious<CR>i

map <C-Tab> :tabnext<CR>
nmap <C-Tab> :tabnext<CR>
imap <C-Tab> <Esc>:tabnext<CR>i
```

I want to switch the tabs with Strg+Tab forward and with Strg+Shift+Tab backward. Why does this mapping not work?

Comment: Your mappings read correct, it's probably your terminal not forwarding the keys.  Check the shell can even receive the ctrl-tab using "read" in bash.  It will block for character input and show you what keystrokes are received. On my xterm, there is no difference between c-tab and c-s-tab. Read shows "^[[Z" for both.  HTH.

Comment: [Why it doesn't work](https://bestasciitable.com/) and [how to make it work in Xterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631241).

Answer (score 10):

Are you using `xterm`? If so, you can't map `ctrl-tab` without a lot of hackery. `xterm` and many other terminal emulators don't recognise `ctrl-tab` and simply send a `tab` character.

See my answer here for more details: [Mapping <C-Tab> in my vimrc fails in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686766/mapping-c-tab-in-my-vimrc-fails-in-ubuntu)

Or you can just use `gvim` if that is suitable - it should work without any mucking around.

Answer (score 1):

Something is probably blocking vim from seeing the C-Tab. This could be your terminal or your window manager.

On some OSes/WMs you can set exceptions to the window manager shortcuts, but how you do this varies crazily between the WMs.

I'm not sure if there is a solution if it is your terminal blocking the key presses.

Comment: The window manager is not the problem. If I switch to a tty-terminal without X11/GUI, the binding still does not work. I use Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 0):

oh ... is it need to be mapped?  just use this predefined combos:

- gt:  == :tabnext
- gT:  == :tabprevious
- [n]gt: == jump to N tab  , e.g.  1gt , 3gt

defining to many short keys is easy, but how can you remember all of them and don't mixing them up with 'ctrl + tab' , 'alt + tab' ( common and usual short keys in most OS )

check this page for more details : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Alternative_tab_navigation

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `xterm`.

Put this in your `.Xresources` file (you can copy-paste in this case):

```
xterm*VT100.Translations: #override \
             Ctrl ~Shift <Key>Tab: string(0x1b) string("[27;5;9~") \n\
             Ctrl Shift <Key>Tab: string(0x1b) string("[27;6;9~")
```

Then do `cd ; xrdb .Xresources` and restart xterm.

---

Put this in your `.vimrc`:

**!! Important** - instead of XXXX you must type <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> and then <kbd>Esc</kbd> **OR** copy-paste the whole text and run `%s/\(set <F1[34]>=\)XXXX/\=submatch(1) . "\33"/g` which is copy-pastable (insert it with `<CTRL-R> +`).

```
set timeout timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=100
set <F13>=XXXX[27;5;9~
nnoremap <F13> gt
set <F14>=XXXX[27;6;9~
nnoremap <F14> gT
```

And restart vim.

Done.