# tmux key bind C-Tab (Ctrl + Tab) to switch/cycle to the next pane

Tags: terminal, tmux, xfce

I'm trying to bind Ctrl + Tab to cycle to the next tab.
I've added this to my ~/.tmux.conf file:

```
bind -n C-Tab select-pane -t :.+
```

But it doesn't work,
however it i change it to Ctrl + a it works fine:

```
bind -n C-a select-pane -t :.+
```

Any ideas?
My first thought is my terminal maybe hijacking it but i cant see anywhere, and nothing happends with Ctrl + Tab normally for me in the terminal, just a tab space is inserted.
I'm using xfce4-terminal if that helps, else maybe im doing something wrong in my tmux conf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470001/bind-ctrltab-and-ctrlshifttab-in-tmux

Comment: @Stan thanks, i hadn't noticed the comments on that question about C-Tab being not yet recognized in the current release, i'll try the not-yet-released code later ta.

Answer (score 1):

*Terminal wont sent  key*. You have the same issues for vim, and so on. The  seams to work because the terminal grabs its, but it wont send to your current job inside it. I **strongly recommend to use other mappings**, ( i know, sounds stupid .... ).

take a look at this post, might help:
[vim cant map <C-Tab> to :tabnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978451/vim-cant-map-c-tab-to-tabnext)