# How to map CTRL+Tab in vim Mac OSX Terminal

Tags: terminal, vim, vi

I'm trying to make Firefox keybindings work for tabs in vim (ssh'd into a server through OSX Terminal), however I'm running into issues.

Its basically the same as this Stack Overflow question except for Terminal in Mac not xterm:

[Mapping <C-Tab> in my vimrc fails in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686766/mapping-c-tab-in-my-vimrc-fails-in-ubuntu)

From my research, it seems some terminals don't differentiate between `<C+Tab>` and `<Tab>`, so I'm wondering if there's some way to hack around this in the Terminal app so vim can understand it. (Maybe escape sequences or something...)

Any ideas?

Comment: <leader><tab> may be a last resort option

Answer (score 3):

Long story short: Ctrl-Tab doesn't exist, because `Tab` is really already a Control key, Ctrl-i.

Short story longer: There is a way to do it, but it requires a sufficiently large amount of hackery at both the terminal and the vim level that you may or may not consider it worth it. I'm working on a much better more generic solution to it but currently I'm not quite sure the world seems to want it.

http://www.leonerd.org.uk/hacks/fixterms/ if you are interested.

Comment: Why does  `:nnoremap <c-c-i> <c-w>w`    also switch the window if only tab is pressed? I had assumed that one needs to press ctr+tab.

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal.app's preferences, you can set some keybindings to send specific character sequences. In your case, you could set `<C-Tab` to send `gt` or whatever Vim shortcut you want.

Anyway, you'd better learn the right shortcuts.