# vim map C-TAB/C-S-TAB to :bn and :bp

Tags: vim

I'm using NerdTree and MiniBufExplorer, and I simply want to switch between my files using Ctrl-Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Tab.

I've tried every combination of [map,remap,noremap,imap] <C-TAB> :bn<Return>

with no success at all.

Comment: checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2695818/668963).

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely the case. I used an alternative character to tab and it works now.

Comment: It won't work because these shortcuts are not recognized. Better get used to `:bn` and `:bp`.

Comment: I'm using Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+Shift+Z. Pretty convenient.

Comment: I use mintty (in windows) and can use `<C-TAB>` to change between different windows in screen. Very useful. For changing buffers I would recommend Ctrlp (which can help you to search based on the buffer name very quickly) or unimpared (another plugin) which defined the mappings [b and ]b to change to previous and next buffer. I got used to these and find them nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping <C-Tab> in my vimrc fails in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686766/mapping-c-tab-in-my-vimrc-fails-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also might want to check this plugin that I made: [Bufstop](https://github.com/mihaifm/bufstop.git)

It's better than `:bn` and `:bp` since it uses the most recently used buffers instead.